# Can a blast hit targets vertically above the caster?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Can a blast hit targets vertically above the caster?

... *trying to draw the situations in text mode* ...

Assuming we have a map like so ...

```
A | B | C 
D | E | F
G | H | I
```

and the caster is in square A, they could do a `Close Blast 2` into **B + C + E + F**, or **E + F + H + I**, etc.

However can they do the blast upwards into **A + B + D + E**, but **one** and **two** squares upwards ?

Comment: I don't know of a written rule on this, but my group hits this situation a lot and our interpretation is this: A blast must start in an adjacent square, and vertical squares are just as adjacent as horizontal ones, so why not? But then you get into more complex situations like casting a Close Blast 5 over the heads of your party members to only hit the large enemies, which for some reason seem less clear... Anyways, good question!

Comment: And welcome to the really quite vile world of 3d in 4e. It's painful.

Comment: Oh I second the woes of 3D in 4E ... but at least we've not got 5F  :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes, it can. Blasts and bursts extend in the third dimension as they do in the second.**

And now for proof.

First, the discussion where this comes up is in dimensional scramble, [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/26958341/?pg=last):

> A Large creature occupies a 2X2X2 cube, and so would be in a burst 1 centred 2 squares up.  If any single square (or cube, in this case) of a multi-square creature is in a burst, it is affected as normal.

As DDI notes in [burst](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=126):

> A burst starts in an origin square and extends in all directions to a specified number of squares from the origin square.

Therefore, it extends a number of "squares" in the third dimension and makes math majors cry.

The way to think of D&D (all editions) handling of flight as stacked 2d grids. moving from grid to grid is always poorly supported and takes effort. A sphere is cubed.

Therefore, from this understanding, if you're supporting (effectively) 2.5d and target "up" X squares, it extends "down" from the "up" you targeted as per the rules. Be prepared for a giant headache though.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, but not in the ways you have specified.**

The blast will create a 2x2x2 cube of effect, however the origin square is **not** included with [blasts](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=125) (as it is on bursts).

> The blast must be adjacent to its origin square, which is a square in your space. The origin square is not affected by the blast.

There is no way to hit square A with a blast.  You can aim upwards and hit A+1, B+1, c+1 and D+1 (as well as the +2 versions of all those).

Comment: "You can aim upwards and hit A+1, B+1, c+1 and D+1 (as well as the +2 versions of all those)." I'm pretty sure that's all he was asking.

Comment: Sorry, my bad ... I was not meaning could the blast hit A, it was A+1 and A+2 as you correctly pointed out